# What are the last 2 bytes in the Start of Scan of a jpeg/jfif image

Tags: java, jpeg

Working on gathering info from a JFIF images I created using Java:

```
Image bmp = ImageIO.read(new File("Background1.png"))
        .getScaledInstance(624, 416, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

BufferedImage tmpBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(bmp.getWidth(null), bmp.getHeight(null),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
Graphics2D g = tmpBufferedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(tmpBufferedImage, "jpg", baos);

.... Written to file later.
```

I have created several images and the headers are identical except for just before the data. Here are some header examples.

```
FF D8 FF...FF DA 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00 F3 EA
FF D8 FF...FF DA 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00 F7 FA
FF D8 FF...FF DA 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00 E2 E8
FF D8 FF...FF DA 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00 F9 FE
```

These are followed by compressed data and end with FF D9.

According to everything I've read on JPEG/JFIF everything after FF DA is supposedly compressed data but why would 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00 always be in every image? Also, if anyone knows, what are those last two bytes? I made several mono color images and all of them have a repeating series that begins after those last two bytes which make me think they must be some kind of header info.

Questions: What are those 12 bytes (0C...00) and especially what are the last 2 bytes?

UPDATE: So those bytes are referred to as Start of Scan and I have found some documentation. 00 0C is a length (12) which makes sense as it adds up to the bytes left in question. There is some other info as to the next 8 bytes or so, but the last ones I'm still not sure of.

FINAL: This was a rabbit hole but I'm going to leave the question in case someone chases the same rabbit. The two bytes at the end are part of the scan data because the 00 0c are apparently included in the count of 12 bytes. This was pointed out by another user on a different question.

Comment: You're not really asking about the last 14 bytes in the header (as in the title); you're more asking about the first 14 bytes of the data.

Comment: I updated my title and added additional info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the layout of the SOS marker.

- FFDA indicates the SOS marker.
- 00OC is the marker length = 12
- 3 = Is the number of components.
  That is followed by the scan IDs, huffman and quantization tables assigned to the scan.

That is followed by the compressed scan data.

Apparently whatever encoder you are using always encodes color images in an interleaved scan (rather than each component in a separate scan).

FFD9 is an EOI marker indicating the end of the JPEG stream.

Comment: @user3344004 I'm accepting this as the answer as it what led me to the answer to my question. I'm going to open another question that I'd like your input on as you seem to know jpeg well judging from other answers I've found here. I will link the question here.

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223310/sending-image-directly-to-epson-projector-trouble-decoding-jpeg-image