# Sending image directly to Epson Projector, trouble decoding jpeg image

Tags: jpeg

I have an Epson Ex5220 that doesn't have a linux driver and have been trying to work out communication through wifi. I can connect and send images captured through packet traces from a Windows machine with a driver but cannot create an acceptable image. Here is where the problem lies:

In the data send, a jpeg image is sent with a header attached like this.

```
00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:02:70:01:a0:00:00:00:07:90:80:85:00

00:00:00:04 - Number of jpeg images being sent (only the first header)
00:00 - X offset
00:00 - Y offset
02:70 - Width of Jpeg image (624 in this case)
01:a0 - Height of Jpeg image (416 in this case)
00:00:00:07:90 - Unknown (I believe it's a version number perhaps)
80:85:00 - (What I'm after) Some count of data units?
```

Following the header is a normal jpeg image. If I strip off that header, I can view the image. Here is a screen shot of a partial capture with the 3 bytes highlighted:

[image: Partial capture showing header]

I have found what seems to be a base line by setting those last three bytes to 80:85:00. Anything less and the image will not project. Also the smallest image size I can send to the projector is a 3w x 1h which correlates with my first two images show below.

Here are some examples:

## 1a - All white (RGB565) image 1024x768 - filesize 12915 - 4 blocks

[image: #1a - All white image 1024x768]

## 2a - Color (RGB565) image 1024x768 - filesize 58577 - only 3 blocks

[image: #2a - Color (RGB565) image 1024x768]

I then changed the 3 bytes to 00:b5:80 (incremented the middle one by 0x30)

## 1b - All white (RGB565) image 1024x768 - filesize 12915 - 22 full rows and 4 blocks.

[image: All white (RGB565) image 1024x768]

## 2b - Color (RGB565) image 1024x768 - filesize 58577 - 7 rows and 22 blocks.

[image: Color (RGB565) image 1024x768]

So it seems that the 3 bytes have something to do with data units. I've read lots of stuff about jpeg and am still digesting much of it but I think if I knew what was required to calculate data units, I'd find my mystery 3 bytes.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

The projector only supports the use of RGB565 jpeg images inside the data send.

Comment: There are no JPEG markers here to use a reference points.

Comment: Where are the 9D's occurring relative to the markers?

Comment: 9D, I guess. where is that relative to the marker?

Comment: I get an error when I try to display either of those images.

Comment: I modified my post because I think it was a little confusing as to my question.

Comment: I've moved your solution to an answer proper. If you still have a question relating to how it works, that would probably be better as a new question, so people notice it.

Comment: No that's fine. I'm done now. I wasn't sure how to close this off because I wanted to leave the info out there in case someone else stumbles upon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I was able to solve this, but I would like to know why this works. Here is the formula for those last 3 bytes:

```
int iSize = bImage.length;
baHeader[17] = (byte) ((iSize) | 0x80);
baHeader[18] =  (byte) ((iSize >> 7) | 0x80);
baHeader[19] = (byte) ((iSize >> 14));
```

I got fed up with messing with it and just look at several images, wrote down all the file sizes and the magic bytes, converted everything to binary and hammered away at ANDing ORing bitshifting until I forced a formal that worked. I would like to know if this is related to calculating jpeg data units. I'm still researching Jpeg but it's not simple stuff!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're misinterpreting how the SOS marker works. Here are bytes you show in one of your examples:

```
SOS = 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00 F9 FE
```

This erroneously has two bytes of compressed data (F9 FE) included in the SOS. The length of 12 (00 0C) includes the 2 length bytes themselves, so there are really only 10 bytes of data for this marker.

The 00 byte before the F9 FE is the "successive approximation" bits field and is used for progressive JPEG images. It's actually a pair of 4-bit fields.

The bytes that you see as varying between images are really the first 2 compressed data bytes (which encode the DC value for the first MCU).

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. If the data you're working with is a JPEG image, then there is no MCU count encoded in the data. You're chasing the wrong info. The MCU count is determined from the image size and color subsampling. For images that are not even multiples of the MCU size, the last row/col MCU has unused pixels in it. By changing the data bytes, you're corrupting the encoded data and causing bad pixels until it resyncs (by chance). Check the JPEG spec for how to interpret the bytes.

Comment: The image size you specified (624 x 416) if color and no subsampling will have 78 x 52 MCUs. The MCU count never needs to be explicitly specified because you calculate it from the image dimensions. The bytes you're looking at may be a checksum. Are you able to decode the images? Without documentation from Epson you may never know what the bytes are, but your guesses are taking you in the wrong direction.

Comment: I looked at your file and it looks like you have everything you need to know. Not knowing what the final few bytes before each JPEG image won't stop you from correctly decoding them. When you "decrease the last 3 bytes", you're corrupting the image data and the decoder will stop decoding at that point (causing you to 'lose' MCUs).

Comment: I modified my post because I think it was a little confusing as to my question.

Comment: I've redone my post so that it is more clear. As you can see it is not a checksum as I can get more and more of the image by increasing the the 3bytes rather then works/doesn't work. You mentioned about the overage of the last row/col. I found that those odd sized mcu's are treated the same as full size so it seems to be a straight forward count of total data units.